# Restrictring user To Enter some Prohibited words in the Address input field, if he enters we have to throw an Error, here i am using react.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have tried this approach to solve this problem,

in this approach, I can validate with the strings present in the **Constant object**,
if the user entered text will consists those words, the function will return **true**, with which I can update the error state in react

```
 const constants = {
     ADDRESS_PROHIBITED_WORDS:'POBOX|POSTBOX|POSTBUS|P.O.B.O.X|PO BOX|POST BOX'
 }
 //here we are assuming that user entered below text
 const userInput = 'pobox 27 gujarat inida'
 
 const checkForProhibitedWords = userInput => {
    const addProhibitedWords = constants.ADDRESS_PROHIBITED_WORDS.split('|')
    const prohibitedWordsCheck = userInput.split(' ').some(eachWord => !addProhibitedWords.every(prohibWord => eachWord.toLowerCase() !== prohibWord.toLowerCase()))
    console.log('---->> checking',prohibitedWordsCheck );
    if (prohibitedWordsCheck) {
      console.log('Eror triggered' );
    }else{
      console.log('Eror removed' );
    }
    return prohibitedWordsCheck
  }
  
  checkForProhibitedWords(userInput);
```

But the actual problem is
I want to validate with space words also like `PO BOX, POST BOX, POST BUS`,
but while using **split(' ')** method on the userInput, it's extracting that word as a seperate one(i.e, for example POBOX it will become two strings as **PO** and **BOX**)..

note :

you may tell that, simply add those also in the Constants object as

```
const constants = {
     ADDRESS_PROHIBITED_WORDS:'POBOX|POSTBOX|POSTBUS|P.O.B.O.X|PO BOX|POST BOX|**PO**|**BOX**'
 }
```

but here according to my requirement, I can't use those strings(it's client requirement)

here I can only able to deal with user Input, not the Strings given by client,

did anyone have any idea ??

So when user enters **POST BOX** or similar words with space, I wanted them to be extracted as same (not only POST BOX, I have a ~100 similar words in my requirement),

Comment: don't split the user input and use regex, you can create a new regex for each of your word

Answer (score 0):

What if after you split it, merge it without spaces?

```js
userInput.split(' ').join('').... // logic goes
```